# your/yours, her/hers etc

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, personal-pronouns

I am if sure if this sentence sounds correct or not,

"you can tell Rachel that your and her hunch was right"

For some reason my brain wants me to change the 'your' to 'yours'. Also should the 'hunch was' be plural or not?

Comment: It may not sound correct - I would hesitate to use it - but it is grammatically fine. I'd probably use: "You can tell Rachel that the hunch both she and you had was right."

Comment: Thank you. I had thought about changing the sentence to "You can tell Rachel that both of your hunches were right" but I felt that this sounded as though the hunches belonged to the person to whom I was speak. Correct?

Comment: Yes - here _both_ refers to the (now two) hunches, not the person/s having them.

Answer (score 3):

*[Your](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/your)* is an adjective, as is *[her](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/her)*. *[Yours](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/yours)* is a pronoun.

In *your* sentence, you are describing the hunch or hunches. *Your* and *her* are correct as adjectives modifying *hunch*.  *Yours*, the pronoun would be used if there were an existing referent which *yours* could relate back to, such as

> You can tell Rachel that *her* hunch was right, as was *yours*

The singular is correct if they shared the same hunch.  It should be plural if they each had a separate or different hunch.